# React Native: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')

Tags: react-native

An error is reported when I run. My code is roughly like this:

App.js :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Text, View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const {navigation}=this.props;
    return (
           <View style={styles.comCardView}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{navigation.navigate('Jwxt')}}>
             <View style={styles.funcView}>
               <Image source={require('./resource/images/icon.png')} style={styles.funcIcon}/>
               <Text style={styles.funcIconDesc}>Touch Here</Text>
             </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        );
       }
      }
```

Jwxt.js :

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';

export default class Jwxt extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>This is JWXT Page</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

navigators/AppNavigators.js :

```js
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation'
import App from '../App'
import Jwxt from '../page/Jwxt'

export const AppStackNavigator=createStackNavigator({
    App:{
        screen:App
    },
    Jwxt:{
        screen:Jwxt
    }
})
```

When I perform the operation, I get this error.

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')
```

Please point out my mistakes and how to modify them. THX :)

Comment: What version of `react-navigation` are you using, because I'm doing it differently inside my codebase.

Comment: I'm guessing version 4.something?

Comment: I'm using `2.18.3` of  `react-navigation`.

Comment: The current maintained version of `react-navigation`  is `6.x.x`, so I would recommend upgrading soon.

Comment: Your current code is working. You said that your "code is roughly like this" so you probably didn't copy the mistake :)

Comment: Btw. Where are you using `AppStackNavigator`? And how are you importing it? I can't but notice that all of your components are exported as default, and the `AppStackNavigator` is a named export.